# StreamBuilder only rerenders the data when I change state with a button

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a StreamBuilder that renders some messages that it fetches from my database server. But I have to change screen or click a button or something else so that it fetches the newly added data. This is necessary because I'm building a messaging screen and I need the data to be fetched once it's sent.
I have followed the pattern for creating a StreamBuilder with all the ifs and else-s, so I don't know where should I make a refresh or setState.

EDIT:
The below code is inside a StatefulWidget and also is called from another StatefulWidget, I don't know if this might help.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MainModel model = Provider.of<MainModel>(context);
    return StreamBuilder<List<Message>>(
        stream: Stream.fromFuture(Provider.of<MainModel>(context)
            .fetchConversationMessages(
            Provider.of<MainModel>(context).selectedConversationId, context)),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
           if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text('${snapshot.error}'));
          }
           else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
                reverse: true,
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Container(
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                child: Text(
                                  '${snapshot.data[snapshot.data.length - index - 1].messageBody}',
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    );

                });
          }
```

Comment: Could you show us your code? That we could see what you've done so far.

Comment: @AmazingBite I added the part where the StreamBuilder is created.